# Realm.js and Fastlane integration

Tags: ios, react-native, realm, fastlane

I am trying to implement fastlane for continuous delivery for a react native project I am working on. However I cannot get Realm.js to play nicely. the error below is ultimately not allowing for `libRealmReact.a` file to be created.

```
▸ Compiling RealmReact.mm
[15:06:45]: ▸ ❌  fatal error:
[15:06:45]: ▸ ❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/Headers/CIImage.h:10:9: could not build module 'CoreVideo'
[15:06:45]: ▸ #import <CoreVideo/CoreVideo.h>
[15:06:45]: ▸  ~~~~~~~~^
[15:06:46]: ▸ Compiling RealmReact.mm
[15:06:46]: ▸ ❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/Headers/EAGLDrawable.h:52:12: attributes may not be specified on a category
[15:06:46]: ▸ @interface EAGLContext (EAGLContextDrawableAdditions)
[15:06:46]: ▸  ~~~~~~~^
[15:06:46]: ▸ ❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAEAGLLayer.h:7:9: could not build module 'OpenGLES'
[15:06:46]: ▸ #import <OpenGLES/EAGLDrawable.h>
[15:06:46]: ▸            ^
[15:06:46]: ▸ ❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:10:9: could not build module 'QuartzCore'
[15:06:46]: ▸ #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
[15:06:46]: ▸  ~~~~~~~^
[15:06:46]: ▸ ❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Headers/CVOpenGLESTexture.h:23:10: could not build module 'OpenGLES'
[15:06:46]: ▸ #include <OpenGLES/gltypes.h>
[15:06:46]: ▸  ~~~~~~~^
[15:06:46]: ▸ ❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/Headers/CIImage.h:10:9: could not build module 'CoreVideo'
[15:06:46]: ▸ #import <CoreVideo/CoreVideo.h>
[15:06:46]: ▸  ~~~~~~~~^
[15:06:46]: ▸ ❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/FileProvider.framework/Headers/NSFileProviderDomain.h:71:12: attributes may not be specified on a category
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find this thread google searching:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43713#issuecomment-584858711

What resolved my issue was removing `anacode` enviroment variables